# Multiple Check Box's Action including Don't Ask Me Again at the When I Clicked Exit Button

Tags: android, checkbox, dialog

[Here  from Dialog Box I keep 3 Check Box,One user can chose one or more that one as they want.As example if one chose clear history and dont ask me again than when i click yes button it clean all history and it never see the dialog in future.My problem is it work fine when chose only one but when chose more that one it get only 1st one .`

```
@Override
    public void closeBrowserFromRightMenu() {

        createExitDialog();
    }

    public void createExitDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        //View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(this, R.layout.alert_layout, null);
        View view = View.inflate(this, R.layout.alart_exit_dialog, null);
        CheckBox dontShowAgain = view.findViewById(R.id.select_3);
        CheckBox clearHistory = view.findViewById(R.id.select_1);
        CheckBox clearCookies = view.findViewById(R.id.cat_select_2);
        //noinspection Convert2Lambda
        view.findViewById(R.id.ritsDialogCancle).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        TextView title = view.findViewById(R.id.ritsDialogTitle);
        title.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.exit_message));
        // TextView message = view.findViewById(R.id.ritsDialogMessage);
        //message.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Button confirm = view.findViewById(R.id.ritsDialogAgree);
        //noinspection Convert2Lambda
        confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String checkBoxResult = "NOT checked";
                if (clearCookies.isChecked()) {
                    Log.e("hgguygujgjjyfg", "clear cookies");
                    WebUtils.clearCookies(BrowserActivity.this);
                    //mMessageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(2);
                }
                if (clearHistory.isChecked()) {
                    Log.e("hgguygujgjjyfg", "clear history");
                    WebUtils.clearHistory(BrowserActivity.this, mHistoryDatabase);
                    //mMessageHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                }


                if (dontShowAgain.isChecked()) {
                    checkBoxResult = "checked";
                    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_ASK_ME, 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString("skipMessage", checkBoxResult);
                    // Commit the edits!
                    editor.apply();
                }





                dialog.dismiss();
                ExitActiivity.exitApplication(BrowserActivity.this);
            }
        });


        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(SETTINGS_ASK_ME, 0);
        String skipMessage = settings.getString("skipMessage", "NOT checked");
        if (!skipMessage.equals("checked")) {
            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.show();

        } else {
            ExitActiivity.exitApplication(BrowserActivity.this);

        }


    }
```

]
[Here is Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tR8zq.png)

Comment: it`s better to use Multi Chose dialog

Comment: How I can use a custom layout with multiple choose alert dialog?Can u provide me a example ?